# How to use jshint for VS 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, jshint

I just download script for JSHint from site and refer in my HTML as external javascript like other JQuery library. It doesnt seems to Get working .. I could not able to find the right way to use jsHint . I search for the Docs .The Configuration part states that

"you can either specify the configuration file manually via the --config flag, use a special file .jshintrc or put your config into your projects package.json file under the jshintConfig property."

Where is config flag located .I Couldnot able to understand it properly ...Please Suggest

Comment: I somehow managed to start working with SharpLinter .. but still couldnot able to worked with jshint

Comment: http://travis.servebeer.com/blog.net/2011/05/13/Adding+An+Easy+Shortcut+To+The+JSHint+Javascript+Validator+To+Visual+Studio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

JSHint is a static analysis tool. To use it from Visual Studio, you would call the executable as part of the build process so that it can check your code and report any errors it finds.

You don't refer to it from HTML at all. It's not a JavaScript library like JQuery is, and it won't run from your users' browsers: it's a tool for finding problems with your JavaScript, and it will run as part of your project build.

In the first instance you can just run JSHint from a console to get it to check your code. In other words, just run `jshint myfile.js` (where `myfile.js` is the name of the JavaScript file you want to check) as described in the [docs](http://jshint.com/docs/).